# Как добавить карту яндекс в подписи к письму на gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, карты, gmail

Всем привет! Есть почта на gmail. Существует возможность к каждому отправленному письму прикреплять подпись, в которую можно помещать ссылки и картинки. Интересует вопрос: а как добавить в него html код и или скрипт, в частности открывающуюся по клику карту яндекс с меткой?
Я понятно выразился или нужны уточнения?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь плагином Better Gmail 2 для добавления html подписи. Вот [ссылка](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-gmail-2/) на плагин

[Тут](http://lifehacker.ru/2008/05/29/better-gmail-2-gmail-na-prokachku/) можно прочитать про него немного

Comment: не очень помогает - используемый плагин удален автором, а альтернативы не понятно как работают: сходу расширенный редактор не запускается

Comment: Я обновил ссылку.

Comment: ну ок - воспользовался, установил, а как его в подпись подключить и использовать?